# How can I create a new column and concatenate some values using php Excel?

Tags: php, excel, concatenation, phpexcel

I want to read an excel file and add a new column to the left of the first column ***on each sheet*** using PHP. (The excel file can have as many as 10 sheets)

2. concatenate "AFS-" to the data in each row of the first column and store the new string in the new column to the left.

Eg. sheet 1
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To insert a single new column before column A:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewColumnBefore('A', 1);
```

Then you can either insert the new values for cells in column 'A' as a formula:

```
for($row = 2; $row = 20; $row++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A'.$row, '="AFS-" && B'.$row);
}
```

or as an absolute value

```
for($row = 2; $row = 20; $row++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A'.$row, 'AFS-' . $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("B".$row)->getValue());
}
```

To do this for all sheets, just iterate over the sheets

**EDIT**

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    ...
}
```

and then reference `$worksheet` instead of `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()`

Comment: Great. Can you explain how to do the iteration of the sheets in your response?

Comment: Why don't you read some of the documentation or look at some of the examples.... a lot of what you're asking is demonstrated there

Comment: I was having a few issues finding exactly what I wanted from the documentation. You explained perfectly.